# Don't apply :before, if certain class is set to the tag (combine :before and :not)

Tags: css, hover

I am styling the underline of a link (`<a href...>`) via the pseudo class `:before`, to get a nice transition effect when hovering.
Now I want to exclude some links, if the have a certain class (for example: `<a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>`).

`a:not(.btn)` is working, but if I try to use `a::before:not(.btn)`, the effect doesn't work anymore.

See this JSFiddle:

Working without `:not`, but the button should not have the effect: https://jsfiddle.net/bzo0nqey/1/

Broken with `:not`: https://jsfiddle.net/bzo0nqey/

I **don't** want to use `<button>` or some other element instead of `<a>`, because this would cost me hours of editing. Moreover, `<a><img></a>` is also having this effect falsely: https://jsfiddle.net/7v9u260j/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put :not before ::before   then its working like intended

a:not(.btn)::before

Comment: This is working! Do you also have an idea for something like this: <a><img></a> ? https://jsfiddle.net/7v9u260j/1/

Comment: mh, that kind of selector: a:not(a > img) is not working in css. if you want to achieve something like this, you have to put an extra class on the a tag.

or:

make some styling to  a>img   and for normal img you reset that styling, then no extra class needed